# "USB power consumption error" (OTG)

Tags: system-error, usb-peripherals, usb-on-the-go

I use a USB OTG cable to connect USB devices such as pen drives, mice, key boards, etc. But when I connect *some devices*, (particularly *some of the pen drives* I have) it gives me following error message and prompts me to disconnect the device.

[image: screencap]

I contacted my OTG cable retailer and he suggested that I should use a USB hub with a power inlet, to connect the devices which give the above error as the said error generated due to heavy power drain from the connected devices (pen drives).

I want to know whether there is a possibility of bricking my phone if I use a USB hub with a power inlet, like this:

[image]

Comment: Which phone is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hub's power should only go to the hub's slave ports, not through the master port back to the phone

But even if the hub uses an odd design, the most it would do is feed the phone 5V and however much amperage it will accept, same as with any bog standard wall charger.

So in short, there's no risk to your phone.

Comment: WRT power, all USB hub controllers I'm familiar with (e.g. [TI's 2136](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tusb2136.pdf)) run either in self-powered mode or bus-powered mode.  In the latter, all power is drawn from the host USB port.  In the latter, all power is drawn from the power adapter and the power line to the host port is not connected to anything, and thus you can't draw power or feed power back to the host device.

Comment: Oh! and Imma catch you if my phone get bricked with the new powered USB HUB. **:evilface:** <offtopic/>